# Generate graph of the imports

Tags: python, import, introspection

I'm getting close to my final goal, which is to generate a nice graph between modules and other imported modules.

For example if x imports from y and z, and y imports from t and v I would like to have:

```
x -> y, z
y -> t, v
```

Now I already have my import hook defined as below, but running it on a simple file I don't get what I would expect:

```
python study_imports.py CollectImports simple.py

('study_imports.py', 'study_imports')
```

Where simple.py actually imports from study_imports.
The problem is that I want to see "simple.py" instead of "study_imports.py", is there a way to get the path of the file actually importing the other module?

```
class CollectImports(object):
    """
    Import hook, adds each import request to the loaded set and dumps
    them to file
    """

    def __init__(self, output_file):
        self.loaded = set()
        self.output_file = output_file

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.loaded)

    def cleanup(self):
        """Dump the loaded set to file
        """
        dumped_str = '\n'.join(x for x in self.loaded)
        open(self.output_file, 'w').write(dumped_str)

    def find_module(self, module_name, package=None):
        #TODO: try to find the name of the package which is actually
        #importing something else, and how it's doing it
        #use a defualtdict with empty sets as the storage for this job
        entry = (__file__, module_name)
        self.loaded.add(str(entry))
```

Comment: Are you aware of [Snakefood's `sfood-graph`](http://furius.ca/snakefood/doc/snakefood-doc.html#seconds-usage-instructions)?

Comment: I am now thanks a lot, this is very nice, but still I would like to make work my version, just for understanding..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe with the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module.

Module a.py

```
import inspect

print inspect.stack()
```

Module b.py

```
import a
```

when running b.py, I got :

```
[
   (<frame object at 0x28a9b70>, '/path/a.py', 5, '<module>', ['print inspect.stack()\n'], 0),
   (<frame object at 0x28a9660>, 'b.py', 2, '<module>', ['import to_import\n'], 0)
]
```

Looks like the second frame contains what you need.

Answer (score 1):

So I looked in snakefood a bit better and I ended up rewriting my code using the AST.
Snakefood still uses the compiler, which is deprecated and much slower than using the ast.

The result is great, for example this is a visitor:

```
from ast import parse, NodeVisitor


class ImportVisitor(NodeVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self.imported = set()
        super(ImportVisitor, self).__init__()

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(x for x in self.imported)

    def visit_Import(self, node):
        for n in node.names:
            self.imported.add(n.name)

    #that we are using
    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        self.imported.add(node.module)
```

Which can be usef for example as:

```
def gen_module_imports(mod):
    try:
        at = parse(open(mod).read())
    except SyntaxError:
        print("file %s has a syntax error, please fix it" % mod)
        return []
    else:
        v = ImportVisitor()
        v.visit(at)
        return v.imported
```

Answer (score 0):

The inspect trick seems to work fine :)
I get something like simple.py: set(['study_imports']) in the imports.log.

```
Class CollectImports(object):
    """
    Import hook, adds each import request to the loaded set and dumps
    them to file
    """

    def __init__(self, output_file):
        self.loaded = defaultdict(lambda: set())
        self.output_file = output_file

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.loaded)

    def cleanup(self):
        """Dump the loaded set to file
        """
        dumped_str = '\n'.join(('%s: %s' % (k, v)) for k, v in self.loaded.items())
        open(self.output_file, 'w').write(dumped_str)

    def find_module(self, module_name, package=None):
        st = inspect.stack()
        self.loaded[st[1][1]].add(module_name)
```